# Undefined reference to boost

Tags: c++, boost

I am getting the following error

```
In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:208: undefined reference to   `boost::system::get_system_category()'
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:209: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
```

I am using a makefile to compile

```
foo: foo.o xyz/libxyz.a
    g++ -g -o foo foo.o xyz/libxyz.a -ljpeg -ltiff

foo.o: foo.cpp
    g++ -I/usr/include/ -g -Ixyz -c foo.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

In the code i have included as follows

```
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
```

How can I resolve this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the link options to the `g++ -o` command where linking is done. The `-l`'s aren't needed at compile time, they're needed at link time.

```
foo: foo.o xyz/libxyz.a
    g++ -g -o foo foo.o xyz/libxyz.a -ljpeg -ltiff -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem

foo.o: foo.cpp
    g++ -I/usr/include/ -g -Ixyz -c foo.cpp
```